# Give permission to dealer_user_role to create users and profile2 fields

Tags: users, 7

I have situation as follows:

I have three types/roles of users.

- AdminRole
- Dealer Role
- CustomerRole

I have given permission to "Dealer Role" to create/add "Customer Role" user. 
That works fine for me.

But my daunting task is as follows:

I am using "Profile2" module for "Customer Role" user.

I have created one profile_type in Profile2 module in which 6 fields are there with separate page for editing profiles page.

Also i have enabled UNIQUE REGISTRATION Path.

Although i have access to the unique registration path when none of the user is logged in system and administrator is log-in.

I want to give "Profile2" module permission in a way that "Dealer Role" having permission to create/add data to the "Customer Role".

In simple, when "Dealer Role" is logged in system, dealer can manage "Customer Role" user.

Thanks
Same

Comment: solved by me any way..

Answer (score 0):

global $user;

$uid = $user->uid;

$accessRoleArr = '';

if(in_array('Admin',$user->roles) || in_array('Dealer',$user->roles) || in_array('Customer',$user->roles))

{ return FALSE; }